# Why does the cost function 'bottom out' and stop improving theta before the model more closely fits my data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, linear-regression

I'm attempting to use polynomial regression to model a data set that looks like f(x)=sin(x). I've used the same code shown below to model data that follow f(x)=sqrt(x) and it worked perfectly. Now my question is why doesn't it work to model this data that follows f(x)=sin(x)? The cost function seems to be working but then it bottoms out and doesn't make any further improvements on theta. Is this approach not the right one to model periodic data like that of f(x)=sin(x)? Or is my hypothesis function wrong to begin with ie. this is wrong h(x)=theta1*x1 + theta2*x2 + theta3*sin(x3) ?

Here is the data

```
 1 0.3598185844161803
 2 -0.5907003710552221
 3 -0.9981321295327847
 4 -0.4878858112400586
 5 0.4709204719060816
 6 0.9967646449427954
 7 0.6061880002347781
 8 -0.3417150963099011
 9 -0.9754469092071643
 10 -0.7123573322832605
 11 0.2056702907377198
 12 0.9346055969515819
 13 0.804268827482698
 14 -0.06550899289804835
 15 -0.8750581473185274
 16 -0.8800828766317587
 17 -0.07596346787988216
 18 0.7979964029172772
 19 0.9382820610212541
 20 0.2159155193317111
 21 -0.7049627550859733
 22 -0.9777015235799271
 23 -0.3515460201960828
 24 0.5978192729185049
 25 0.9975522834966486
 26 0.4801403250760301
 27 -0.4787104339389342
 28 -0.9974370276767179
 29 -0.5991246180850541
 30 0.3500202023692713
 31 0.9773580629661545
 32 0.7061174277895922
 33 -0.2143243140693618
 34 -0.9377172699801594
 35 -0.7989772923759523
 36 0.07433872316613974
 37 0.8793080594598693
 38 0.8758456210230737
 39 0.06713475778668974
 40 -0.8032994921509787
 41 -0.9351838936104485
 42 -0.2072645361059621
 43 0.7112128800449653
 44 0.9758044542087929
 45 0.3432459133258594
 46 -0.6048913373092379
 47 -0.9968942820215474
 48 -0.4723572212567733
 49 0.486462890344544
 50 0.9980312640016475
```

Here is my code

```
% h(x) = theta1*x1 + theta2*x2 + theta3*sin(x3)

format long

function norm_x = normalizeFeatures(X)
    X = (X-mean(X))./std(X);
    X(isnan(X)) = 1;
    norm_x = X;
end

function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
    m = length(y);
    square_errors = (X*theta-y).^2;
    J = 1/(2*m)*sum(square_errors);
end

function [j_his, theta] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters)
    m = length(y);
    for i=1:iters
        theta -= (alpha/m)*(X'*(X*theta-y));
        j_his(i, 1) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
    end
    j_his = j_his;
    theta = theta;
end

data = load('sinusoidal-data.txt');
figure(1)
plot(data(:, 1), data(:, 2), 'color', 'red', '-*');
hold on

X = data(:, 1);
y = data(:, 2);

X = [ones(size(X, 1), 1), X];
X = [X, sin(X(:, 2))];
X = normalizeFeatures(X);

theta = [0; 0; 0];
alpha = 0.01;
iters = 1000;

[j_his, theta] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters);

predictions = X*theta;
plot(data(:, 1), predictions, 'color', 'blue', '-*');

figure(2)
plot([1:iters], j_his, 'color', 'green', 'linewidth', 2);
```

Below are 2 graphs- 
The first graph shows the actual data(red) along with my predicted values(blue). 
The second graph shows the cost function value decreasing as gradient descent iterates

[image: actual data(red) vs my predictions(blue) after using gradient descent to find an optimal value for theta]

[![cost function decreasing after each iteration within gradient descent 
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4wuU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4wuU.png)

**update**
I changed one line in my code and have been able to get much better results, however i'm not positive as to why this worked but I thought maybe this is why...
Since gradient descent uses the derivative of the cost function, and cos(x) = d/dx sin(x) , I changed this line `X = [X, sin(X(:, 2))];` to `X = [X, cos(X(:, 2))];`. Additionally, Looking at the graph of my previous results above one can see how the mid-point of the waves of my predictions(blue) match up with the peaks and troughs of the actual values(red), and vice versa, thus would be the relationship between graphs of sin(x) and cos(x). Here is the new graph of predictions where the value of the cost function is 0.0101 (vs previously 0.2385).

[image]

Comment: When I look at a scatterplot of the data it does not appear to follow a sine wave, rather it seems almost random.

Comment: Look at my image, if the line weren't drawn thru all the points they would look random to most too.  Draw a line thru your points to see the oscillation

Comment: I understand. I got good results fitting your data to the equation "y = sin(X  + shift)" with a value for the parameter shift = 1.7735192060842964E+00 try fitting that equation and see if you get a similar value for the shift parameter.

Comment: That seems to work but I also just tried something interesting that caused my model to fit the data very well. In my code I changed the line `X = [X, sin(X(:, 2))];` to `X = [X, cos(X(:, 2))];` . I did this because Gradient Descent uses the derivative of the inner term and I remembered the derivative of sin(x)=cos(x). Also looking at my graph you can see the peaks & troughs of my predictions match the midlines of the actual data which is the case when plotting sin(x) alongside cos(x). The new value for the cost function now is 0.0101,  opposed to the previous value of 0.2385 when using sin(x).

Comment: So I seemed to have found my solution although I have to test it a few more times to see if my is the rule or an exception. Do you know the answer to that? If this is a rule then this must be something well known in the community that I've overlooked. Any advice or pointers toward literature would be great, thanks.